# OnItemClickListener doesn't work with a specific Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I looked here about the problem, but I didn't find the answer for me.

My onClickListener doesn't work in the following fragment. But it works on other fragments. I'm not shure, if there any mistake at the listener or that i forget something.

```
public class StuffFragment extends Fragment {

public View rootview;
private TravelDataSource dataSource;
private StuffDataSource dataSource_stuff;

public StuffFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stuff, container, false);
    id = getID();
    getStuffList(id);
    showAllStuff(id)
    return rootview;
}

public void showAllStuff(long id) {
    ArrayList<Stuff> arrayOfStuff = dataSource_stuff.getStuffForList(id, "false");
    StuffAdapter adapter = new StuffAdapter(getContext(), arrayOfStuff);
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.listviewStuffList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    /*Fix für die Höhe*/
    setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listView);

    /*OnClick Listener*/

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            System.out.println("Knobb gedrückt");
        }
    });
}
```

Layout xml file

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="de.christian_heinisch.packliste.StuffFragment"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding">

    <TextView
        android:text="Stadtname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewCityname"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large"
        android:textColor="@color/colorHeadline"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="14.01.2017 - 21.01.2017"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTravelDate"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:text="Nicht vergessen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView10" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listviewStuffList" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Anzahl"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/editText_quantity"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:id="@+id/editText_product"
            android:layout_weight="4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+"
            android:id="@+id/button_add_product" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:text="Muss noch gekauft werden"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView12" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listviewStuffBuy"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Anzahl"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/editText_quantity_buy"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:id="@+id/editText_product_buy"
            android:layout_weight="4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+"
            android:id="@+id/button_add_product_buy" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: you haven't called `showAllStuff(id)` method anywhere.

Comment: Where do you use your showAllStuff function?

Comment: Sorry, there was a copy / paste mistake at my question. I correct the code. I call it at the oneCreateView.

Comment: check the "clickable" and "focusable" property of the listview first.

Comment: I check the clickable. It wasn't set. I set it on true, but it don't work. I update my question with the layout xml

Comment: For your information, your "required" constructor isn't required at all: the compiler will automatically add an empty, `public` constructor if you haven't defined *any* constructor of that class yourself.

Comment: @ChristianHeinisch Check my answer man

Comment: @W4R10CK  I try your example, but it don't work.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. The problem was at the listitem.xml. There is a checkbox. If I at the attribute "android:focusable="false" " it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try code:

```
public class StuffFragment extends Fragment {

public View rootview;
private ListView listView; 
private TravelDataSource dataSource;
private StuffDataSource dataSource_stuff;

public StuffFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stuff, container, false);
listView = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.listviewStuffList);
id = getID();
getStuffList(id);
showAllStuff(id)
return rootview;
}

public void showAllStuff (long id) {

ArrayList<Stuff> arrayOfStuff = null;
arrayOfStuff = dataSource_stuff.getStuffForList(id, "false");

StuffAdapter adapter = new StuffAdapter(getContext(), arrayOfStuff);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
/*Fix für die Höhe*/
setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listView);

/*OnClick Listener*/

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        System.out.println("Knobb gedrückt");
    }
});

}
```